# Android TabHost initial tab has incorrect text color

Tags: android, android-theme, android-tabs

I'm using TextViews as indicators on my TabHost. I use a custom background for the text view, but I do nothing with the text color. In my activity's onCreate method, I have no problem setting the current tab.

When I start up the activity, the background of the selected tab is displayed correctly, so is the tab's content, but the text color for both tabs is initially light-gray. Once I click on either tab, however, the text color of the selected tab from then on is black. I can't seem to find a way to programmatically select the tab in a way that updates the text color to black, like it does when you actually click on the tab. I tried:

- calling setCurrentTab on the tab host
- calling setCurrentTab on the tab widget
- calling focusCurrentTab on the tab widget
- calling setSelected(true) on the indicator text view
- calling setSelected(true) on the tab widget's child view

In summary, I don't want to apply a custom text color. I just want it to use the default theme's color, but I want the state of the tab after programmatically selecting it to be exactly the same as it is after clicking on it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm seeing the same issue using MonoDroid.

```
// Set current tab to ScheduleTab
TabHost.CurrentTab = 1;
// TODO Focus not working completely
TabHost.TabWidget.FocusCurrentTab(1);
```

The correct tab is set and is active, however the text color is light grey instead of black. If touch input is used to select a tab then the text color changes to black, but it doesn't when set programmatically.

The bottom strip indicator is also rendered correctly, just not the text color.

The fix I found was to create and use an explicit selector for setting the text color.

drawable/TabTextColors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#444"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#444"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#444"/>
    <item android:color="#ccc"/>
</selector>
```

And then reference it from my tab view.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="TITLE"
        android:textSize="13dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@drawable/TabTextColors" />
```